# Xcode removes privacy keys from Info.plist and then does not let me upload archive to App Store

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, permissions, info.plist

My iOS app requests photos, reminders, and health permissions from the users. I developed and released these features one by one. As I went along, I added all the corresponding request permission description keys (like `NSRemindersUsageDescription`) into the `info.plist` and everything works fine.

However, every time I archive the app they all disappear from the `info.plist`. Now however, these keys do exist in the `Build Settings` `User Defined` section

[image]

I cannot upload the app to App Store connect unless these keys are in the `info.plist`, so every time I just add them again. But what is the issue here?

Xcode removes the keys from `info.plist` and and then does not let me upload the archive to the App Store because the keys are not in the `info.plist`?!

Comment: They are now automatically moved to Project -> Target -> Info in the newer versions of Xcode.

Comment: @koropok But Xcode does not let me upload the build to app store unless the keys are in the info.plist.